# Import custom ascii format from file

Tags: c#

I need to import an ascii file with a custom file-format.

Some data is stored in blocks, with a start block and end block. Other data is stored without block delimiters.

One example is:
***$Sheet***
**S** posx posy dimx dimy
List of Sheet Labels
**$EndSheet**

Another is:
**Text Notes** posx posy orientation dimension ~
Text

Now what would be the best/most generic way to import these data into some kind of structure?

Regards
Jakob Justesen

Comment: Your goal's a bit unclear -- can you define best? If you've only two file formats and you just need a one off tool to get it, then generic might not be a useful second goal.

Comment: You've not really provided enough information for a meaningful answer.

Comment: I written a number of file readers for file formats I did not create (are you trying to import a file created by another application which you don't have the source code?). You need to know the delimiters of the data, if fields are optional etc. Without that knowledge you cannot define the parser.

Comment: There's not enough information to be able to formulate a best answer, or even a rough answer.  With only two formats, there also doesn't really seem to be a need for this to be generic at all.  What have you tried?  Have any source code so that we can see what direction you were headed in?

Comment: Thanks for your reply's.  Those two where just examples, there is a bunch of other blocks, one could be $Comp, and ect... My main point was just how to best import ascii data from a file. Not the exact code, but just the best principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to read a line: if it's a block start then hand off to a method that will handle a block read.  If it's not, then hand off to a method that will handle a non-block read.

The most "generic" way to do that is to have a factory method that returns you the requisite Reader class.  Some pseudo code might look like this:

```
Open [File]
while not EOF
  Read [Line]
  var [Reader] = ReaderFactory.GetReader([Line])
  var [Record] = [Reader].Read([File])
  Do what you want with record
wend
Close [File]
```

How you represent the different record types I leave as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Thanks! this looks like something I could use. Good idea with the ReaderFactory.